# foundation 6 top-bar out of the box does not look correct

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to use Foundation (for the first time) and I am not a front-end developer so it is difficult for me to know why the nav bar looks jacked up.

Here is the html source...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

      <title>foundation-rails</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/_settings.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/foundation_and_overrides.self-9f702220def22f6bba60926251969c326c0b2aaed013f64de3441ca676c1e678.css?body=1" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/application.self-167193cd81d9330d9ddb5c4ec7b44214fea529aa8a94f3a86e6526e4f652fc02.css?body=1" />
      <script src="/assets/vendor/modernizr.self-74da3245def7569da28115667be6a85a2ad97464abe707c9829c46d8975597bc.js?body=1"></script>
      <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
      <meta name="csrf-token" content="pK3Wes1fbRRHZ2j3xELVaaU3xh8YU6pGcCFJJKej2jY3XHKi6FnOnZJPizR1whs63vMFeAtJu9WI8exWG/wk5Q==" />
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="top-bar">
        <div class="top-bar-left">
          <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
            <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
            <li>
              <a href="/products">Browse Products</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/products">Price List</a></li>
            <li><a href="/products">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="/products">Cart</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p id="notice"></p>
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th colspan="3"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>

      <a class="button" href="/products/new">New Product</a>
      <!-- Sidebar -->
      <aside class="large-3 columns">
        <h5>Categories</h5>
        <ul class="side-nav">
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Code</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Fun</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Weasels</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="panel">
          <h5>Featured</h5>
          <p>Pork drumstick turkey fugiat. Tri-tip elit turducken pork chop in. Swine short ribs meatball irure bacon nulla pork belly cupidatat meatloaf cow.</p>
          <a href="#">Read More &rarr;</a>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <!-- End Sidebar -->
    </body>
  </html>
```

Here is what it looks like...
[image]

This is using Rails 4.2.5 with the foundation-rails gem.

Comment: looks like you have not added the reference to foundation css correctly. Are you using foundation 6 with SAAS ?

Comment: Yes I am using saas as part of rails,  the gem did not insert anything into the application.scss so I am not sure what is supposed to go there.

Comment: Also the styling you see in the menu is all from Foundation, so I am not sure but it would seem some css is coming from Foundation.

Comment: I tested the same code with foundation 6. every thing looks great. the only thing you are missing is about the saas compiler somehow is not working correctly in your case.
in my case I am using GIT Bash shell.

Comment: So i don't know what that means, did you create a rails app and use the gem?

Comment: I followed the official documentation of foundation https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html. I used git bash as a cli for it not rails